# Transport Agent Exchange 2013 Online

Tags: ajax, powershell, sharepoint, outlook, exchange-server

I need to change the way Exchange processes the header "Reply-To", for incoming messages created by the mail functionality of SharePoint 2013.
In order to do this, I want to start giving you some precisions on the problem:

**Environments involved:**
SharePoint Online 2013, Exchange Online 2013, both included in an Office 365 instance for Education.

**Technologies and languages involved:**
Javascript, Ajax, CSOM, Powershell cmdlets for Exchange Online.

**Description of the implemented solution for messaging:**
We need to send emails from a SharePoint Site Collection, to members contained on it, and in order to do that, we use the SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail function.

**Problem related with this solution:**
This function does not allow the user to define of the header "reply-to", and always sends in this field "no-reply@sharepointonline.com". So, even when you see in Outlook the name of the sender(which is defined in the header "from"), when you press the button "reply", Outlook takes the value of the header reply-to, which is not the sender.

**Question:**
Since is not posible to override the header "reply-to" by sending it as another field in the ajax query, I want to know if is it possible to write an Exchange's Transport Agent in order to change always the header "reply-to" with the value in "from", if they not match. And also, I need to know if a Transport Agent may be installed in Exchange Online, since the cmdlet is not available from Powershell.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Exchange Online/Office365 Transport Agents aren't an option they can only be used when Mail is routed through an On Premise Exchange server.

My suggest would be use a method other then SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail to send email. Eg you could build your own method that use EWS or new Unified endpoint https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages. To Send a Message as a user you will need to provide some form of valid security context that has rights to do so (which is probably the real reason SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail doesn't allow you send as another user).

Cheers
Glen